# ¿Cómo enviar mensajes de error de email o contraseña del controlador a una View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Cuando en el formulario de la vista `Index.cshtml` escribo email y password, esos datos van al `ActionResult Principal()` del controlador.

En el `ActionResult Principal()` tengo una función que verifica si existe el email en la base de datos y otra función que verifica si el password pertenece a ese email.

Si los datos son correctos, muestro la `View principal.cshtml`. Pero el problema es cuando los datos son incorrectos. Lo que quiero hacer es que si el email no existe, volver a la View `Index.cshtml` y mostrarle un aviso de que el email ingresado no existe. Y en caso de que la contraseña sea incorrecta avisarle también.

Qué podría hacer para solucionarlo? dejo el código:

```
    public ActionResult Principal()
    {
        String email = Request.Form["email"];
        String password = Request.Form["password"];
        UsserService us = new UsserService();
        bool exist = true;
        //aca funcion que verifica si existe email.
        bool R = us.SearchEmailUsser(email);

        if (R == false)
        {
            //ir al index y avisar que no existe el email
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Usser");
        }
        else
        {
            //Aca si el email existe comprueba que la contraseña pertenezca al mismo email
            exist = us.SearchEmailPasswordUsser(email, password);
        }

        if (exist == true)
        {  
            ViewBag.Email = email;//le paso el email a principal.cshtml para el nav
            return View(); //va a la pagina principal.cshtml
        }
        else
        {
            //Ir al Index y mostrar mensaje de que la contraseña no es valida
            //return View(index);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Hola, como se llama el Controlador?. La Acción `Principal()` e `Index()` están en el mismo Controlador?. Podrías indicar que tioenes en la Acción `Index()` ??

Comment: Hola Rafael! , si la acción Principal() e Index() estan en el mismo contolador llamado UsserController. Respecto a la Accion Index() solo tengo el return view(); sin nada mas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio deberías hacer lo mismo que estás haciendo cuando el email y password son correctos, o sea, almacenar en el `ViewBag` el mensaje y retornar la Vista correspondiente.

Esto ya lo estás haciendo en tu código:

```
    if (exist == true)
    {  
        ViewBag.Email = email;//le paso el email a principal.cshtml para el nav
        return View(); //va a la pagina principal.cshtml
    }
```

Ahora solo debes seguir el mismo razonamiento para ir a la Vista `Index()`:

```
    if (R == false)
    {
        //ir al index y avisar que no existe el email
        ViewBag.Msg = "No existe el Email";
        return View("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        //Aca si el email existe comprueba que la contraseña pertenezca al mismo email
        exist = us.SearchEmailPasswordUsser(email, password);
    }

    if (exist == true)
    {  
        ViewBag.Email = email;//le paso el email a principal.cshtml para el nav
        return View(); //va a la pagina principal.cshtml
    }
    else
    {
        //Ir al Index y mostrar mensaje de que la contraseña no es valida
        ViewBag.Msg = "La contraseña no es válida.";
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Luego en la Vista `Index`, recuperas del `ViewBag` el mensaje así:

```
<p>Mensaje: @ViewBag.Msg </p>
```

Comment: Gracias! funciona perfectamente!

Comment: @Claudio: Estupendo!. Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta, 
y marcar el check verde al lado de la respuesta que te ha solucionado la pregunta, 
con eso estarás colaborando con la buena salud de este sitio. Gracias.

Comment: Perfecto @Rafael! ahí valoré la respuesta, pondría 10 pero solo permite 1 jaja muchas gracias!